# Downgrading PHP 5.4 to 5.3 on CentOS 6.5?

Tags: centos, php, php5

I am trying to downgrade PHP from 5.5.8 to 5.3.x. 
I have tried this  but it dint work for me.

```
yum downgrade php
```

The error I have got is

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Downgrade Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* Webmin: webmin.mirror.somersettechsolutions.co.uk
* base: centos.excellmedia.net
* epel: epel.mirror.net.in
* extras: centos.excellmedia.net
* updates: centos.excellmedia.net
No Match for available package: php-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64
Nothing to do
```

I have also tried  this but even this dint work for me.

```
sudo yum downgrade php php-common php-cli
```

The error log I  have got is

```
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
    Setting up Downgrade Process
    Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
     * Webmin: webmin.mirror.somersettechsolutions.co.uk
     * base: centos.excellmedia.net
     * epel: epel.mirror.net.in
     * extras: centos.excellmedia.net
     * updates: centos.excellmedia.net
    No Match for available package: php-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64
    Resolving Dependencies
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.3.3-27.el6_5 will be a downgrade
    ---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.5.8-1.el6.remi will be erased
    ---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.3-27.el6_5 will be a downgrade
    ---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.5.8-1.el6.remi will be erased
    ---> Package php-pecl-zip.x86_64 0:1.12.4-1.el6.remi.5.5 will be obsoleted
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution
    Error: Package: php-pecl-memcached-2.1.0-7.el6.remi.5.5.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               Requires: php(api) = 20121113-64
               Removing: php-common-5.5.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
                   php(api) = 20121113-64
               Downgraded By: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
                   php(api) = 20090626
               Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
                   php(api) = 20090626
    Error: Package: php-process-5.5.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.8-1.el6.remi
               Removing: php-common-5.5.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
                   php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.8-1.el6.remi
               Downgraded By: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
                   php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5
               Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
                   php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-26.el6
    Error: Package: php-pecl-igbinary-1.1.2-0.5.git3b8ab7e.el6.remi.1.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
               Removing: php-common-5.5.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
                   php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
               Downgraded By: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
                   php(zend-abi) = 20090626
               Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
                   php(zend-abi) = 20090626
    Error: Package: php-pecl-memcached-2.1.0-7.el6.remi.5.5.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
               Removing: php-common-5.5.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
                   php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
               Downgraded By: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
                   php(zend-abi) = 20090626
               Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
                   php(zend-abi) = 20090626
    Error: Package: php-pecl-mongo-1.4.5-1.el6.remi.5.5.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
               Removing: php-common-5.5.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
                   php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
               Downgraded By: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
                   php(zend-abi) = 20090626
               Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
                   php(zend-abi) = 20090626
    Error: Package: php-pecl-mongo-1.4.5-1.el6.remi.5.5.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               Requires: php(api) = 20121113-64
               Removing: php-common-5.5.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
                   php(api) = 20121113-64
               Downgraded By: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
                   php(api) = 20090626
               Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
                   php(api) = 20090626
    Error: Package: php-pecl-igbinary-1.1.2-0.5.git3b8ab7e.el6.remi.1.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               Requires: php(api) = 20121113-64
               Removing: php-common-5.5.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
                   php(api) = 20121113-64
               Downgraded By: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
                   php(api) = 20090626
               Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
                   php(api) = 20090626
    Error: Package: php-gd-5.5.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.8-1.el6.remi
               Removing: php-common-5.5.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
                   php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.8-1.el6.remi
               Downgraded By: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
                   php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5
               Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
                   php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-26.el6
    Error: Package: php-pecl-sqlite-2.0.0-0.4.svn332053.el6.remi.5.5.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
               Removing: php-common-5.5.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
                   php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
               Downgraded By: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
                   php(zend-abi) = 20090626
               Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
                   php(zend-abi) = 20090626
    Error: Package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-1.el6.remi.1.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
               Removing: php-common-5.5.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
                   php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
               Downgraded By: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
                   php(zend-abi) = 20090626
               Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
                   php(zend-abi) = 20090626
    Error: Package: php-pecl-apcu-4.0.3-1.el6.remi.5.5.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
               Removing: php-common-5.5.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
                   php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
               Downgraded By: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
                   php(zend-abi) = 20090626
               Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
                   php(zend-abi) = 20090626
    Error: Package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-1.el6.remi.1.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               Requires: php(api) = 20121113-64
               Removing: php-common-5.5.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
                   php(api) = 20121113-64
               Downgraded By: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
                   php(api) = 20090626
               Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
                   php(api) = 20090626
    Error: Package: php-mbstring-5.5.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.8-1.el6.remi
               Removing: php-common-5.5.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
                   php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.8-1.el6.remi
               Downgraded By: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
                   php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5
               Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
                   php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-26.el6
    Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.5.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.8-1.el6.remi
               Removing: php-common-5.5.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
                   php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.8-1.el6.remi
               Downgraded By: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
                   php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5
               Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
                   php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-26.el6
    Error: Package: php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.3-1.el6.remi.5.5.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
               Removing: php-common-5.5.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
                   php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
               Downgraded By: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
                   php(zend-abi) = 20090626
               Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
                   php(zend-abi) = 20090626
    Error: Package: php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.3-1.el6.remi.5.5.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               Requires: php(api) = 20121113-64
               Removing: php-common-5.5.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
                   php(api) = 20121113-64
               Downgraded By: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
                   php(api) = 20090626
               Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
                   php(api) = 20090626
    Error: Package: php-xml-5.5.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.8-1.el6.remi
               Removing: php-common-5.5.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
                   php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.8-1.el6.remi
               Downgraded By: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
                   php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5
               Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
                   php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-26.el6
    Error: Package: php-pecl-apcu-4.0.3-1.el6.remi.5.5.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               Requires: php(api) = 20121113-64
               Removing: php-common-5.5.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
                   php(api) = 20121113-64
               Downgraded By: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
                   php(api) = 20090626
               Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
                   php(api) = 20090626
    Error: Package: php-pecl-sqlite-2.0.0-0.4.svn332053.el6.remi.5.5.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               Requires: php(api) = 20121113-64
               Removing: php-common-5.5.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
                   php(api) = 20121113-64
               Downgraded By: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
                   php(api) = 20090626
               Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
                   php(api) = 20090626
    Error: Package: php-pdo-5.5.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.8-1.el6.remi
               Removing: php-common-5.5.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
                   php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.8-1.el6.remi
               Downgraded By: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
                   php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5
               Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
                   php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-26.el6
     You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
     You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
    [root@centos1 /]# php -v
    PHP 5.5.8 (cli) (built: Jan  9 2014 08:14:44)
    Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
    Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have a installed a lot of additional PHP modules from remi repository. When you downgrade PHP, there dependencies are not available anymore. You could try to downgrade them as well

```
yum downgrade php*
```

But this will probably also fail as not all of these packages are available in the standard repositories

I'd suggest to remove all PHP packages first:

```
yum remove php*
```

Afterwards, you can reinstall the packages you need from the standard repo:

```
yum install php php-cli ...
```

Comment: Ya now it is Installed PHP 5.3 Successfully.